# C++11 explicit conversion operators/constructors in return statement

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a following example (with overly safe boolean type):

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct boolean_type
{

    explicit
    boolean_type(bool _value)
        : value_(_value)
    { ; }

    explicit
    operator bool () const
    {
        return value_;
    }

private :

    bool value_;

};

struct A
{

    A(int const _i) 
        : i_(_i)
    { ; }

    boolean_type operator == (A const & _other) const
    {
        return (i_ == _other.i_);
    }

private :

    int i_;

};

bool t()
{
    return A(0) == A(0);
}

int main()
{ 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It is well-known that such code containing an errors: "could not convert '(((int)((const A*)this)->A::i_) == ((int)*other.A::i*))' from 'bool' to 'boolean_type'" in return statement of `bool A::operator == (A const &) const` and "cannot convert 'boolean_type' to 'bool'" in return statement of `bool t()`. But what the risk here? Why there are not explicit conversion here in both cases? Why are implicit? In fact we explicitly specify the returning type `bool` in second case and `static_assert(std::is_same< bool, decltype(std::declval< int >() == std::declval< int >()) >::value, "!");` as such!

Additionally want to say:

Due to the specified obstruction I cannot simply replace all entries of the `bool` to my super-safe `boolean_type` (which is *mocked-object*) in my user code, because, say, in return statement of `boost::variant::operator ==` uses above construction, that treats there as **implicit conversion**. Similar obstructions are not unique.

Comment: There is no duplicate at all in **Q**, because there is a consideration of significand details implied in the discussion.

Comment: Where did this code come from?

Comment: @VaughnCato This code is purely artificial.

Comment: There has been a lot of debate in the committee about this very question (should return imply an explicit conversion to the return type)...

Comment: @MarcGlisse I think it's absolutely inevitable. Have you the link?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find this question entirely incomprehensible.

Comment: @Dukales those I remember were not public conversations. But you could search the wg21 issue lists and the isocpp.org mailing lists.

Comment: See this link for some insight: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Comment: @MarcGlisse:  Personally I hope that doesn't go anywhere.  A conversion without a conversion *statement* is implicit.  Making `return` an explicit conversion operator flies in the face of what has always been before.

Comment: @JohnDibling `return` is a very special case. You have spelled out the type to convert to a few lines above. This is not the same as converting to some random type that is never mentioned in the function. Then it becomes a matter of taste. I think having to repeat the type in every return statement is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

You have two implicit conversions. One here:

```
return (i_ == _other.i_);
```

And another here:

```
return A(0) == A(0);
```

These are implicit because you are not explicitly telling the compiler that you want to convert the result of the comparisons to `boolean_type` and `bool` respectively. These implicit conversions are not allowed because you made both the constructor and conversion operator of `boolean_type` `explicit` - that's the whole point of the `explicit` keyword.

You would need to do:

```
return static_cast<boolean_type>(i_ == _other.i_);
```

And:

```
return static_cast<bool>(A(0) == A(0));
```

The typical reason for making conversions to `bool` explicit is because the conversion may be used in situations that you did not intend it to be used. For example, if you had `boolean_type` objects called `b1` and `b2` with non-`explicit` conversions, you would be able to do the following:

```
b1 > 0
b1 == b2
```

These are probably not the intended uses of the boolean conversion operator.

Comment: But what about the risk?

Comment: @Dukales The risk is that you never intended `bool`s to be implicitly converted to `boolean_type` and vice versa. If that's not a risk, you shouldn't make them `explicit`. By making them `explicit`, it is you that has declared there is a risk.

Comment: I see evident risk here: `boolean_type(false) + boolean_type(true);`, but not in above examples.

Comment: One can argue that specifying the return type of the function is already a very explicit way to say what type you want to return.

Comment: @MarcGlisse:  I disagree.  This isn't VB.  I don't say that to be flippant, but to express that it goes against the idea that "you don't get what you don't use," and the corrolary, "you don't use what you don't ask for."

Comment: @JohnDibling Let's agree to disagree. I asked for a conversion by specifying the return type of the function. The standard trying to nanny me and forcing me to use baby-speak by repeating things many times is just a pain.

Comment: @MarcGlisse:  I agree to agree to disagree. :)  If given the opportunity, I will fight this with my dying breath.  I **hate** the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Why there are not explicit conversion here in both cases?

Because the onus is on *you*, the programmer, to be explicit if you want an explicit conversion.

Implicit conversions would work in this case if you had allowed them.  But you didn't allow them when you marked `operator bool` and `boolean_type::boolean_type` as `explicit`.

> Why are implicit?

Because you did not write the conversion.  You must:

```
  boolean_type operator == (A const & _other) const
  {   
      return boolean_type (i_ == _other.i_);
  }
```

...and:

```
bool t()
{   
    return (bool) (A(0) == A(0));
}
```

> But what the risk here?

You tell us.  `explicit` exists specifically to tell the compiler that there might be a risk in permitting some implicit conversions to take place.  So when you marked those functions as `explicit` you said to the compiler:

> Ok, if you allow an implicit conversion from a bool to a
>   boolean_operator or vice versa, something bad might happen.  So don't
>   allow those implicit conversions.

You didn't tell the compiler (or us) *why* those implicit conversions are dangerous.  You only said that they *were*.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144568/c11-explicit-conversion-operators-constructors-in-return-statement/21144749?noredirect=1#comment31823378_21144749 ?

Comment: @Dukales:  Sure, ok.  I can probably come up with some contrived examples where an implicit conversion is either exactly what you want or not what you want, but that's not the point.  The point is you told the compiler to not permit these implicit conversions, and then tried to employ one.  So the risk there, as far as the compiler is concerned, is if it had allowed those implicit conversions then it would be doing something you told it not to do.

Comment: In present state this `explicit` conversion constructors/conversion operators is little useless. See the addition in the **Q**.